# Python Scikit learn OneHotEncoder to encode select values only

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Can I use OneHotEncoder to one hot encode only a select values in a category column instead of constructing a dense ndarray and then dropping the unnecessary columns?

For example,
If a categorical column named color has 3 colors say red, green and blue and I would like to one hot encode only 2 of those values say "red" and "green", how would I do that with OneHotEncoder?

I am new to ML, so also would like to know is it advisable and common thing to do such limited one hot encoding especially dealing with column having way too many categorical values?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you only dropping column or are you dropping multiple columns?

Comment: You either use one-hot encoding on a column using all values else not do it at all. If you are trying to one-hot encode some vales and keep some vales as they are, I don't see a way in which you would be able to use them in ML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking to drop one of the categories in each column so that you're fitting against a baseline, you can add a `drop` attribute at the `OneHotEncoder` object initialization.

This will drop the first value encountered in the column

```
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop='first')
```

If you have 2 columns you want to encode and have specific values you want to not encode in each column:

```
dropList = ['Blue','Triangle']
ohe = OneHotEncoder(drop=dropList)
```

Will not encode `'Blue'` in the first column and not encode `'Triangle'` in the second column.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to tell the encoder what values to keep as opposed to drop?

Comment: @toddlermenot You might want to define another column specifying values you want to keep and then running OHE on that new column then, e.g `df['SpecialOHE'] = df['Column'].apply(lambda x: x if x in [values you want to keep] else 'not interested')` because skipping out on multiple columns means you're purposefully removing information that could be used, and most of the time you wouldn't want to do that so Sklearn didn't design that functionality

Comment: @toddlermenot  The reason they designed the drop one value to OHE is because sometimes one of the categories is a baseline for example a column called `disease` has `['Not Sick', 'Lung Cancer', 'Ol' Rona', 'The Plague']` etc. and they don't need to encode `'Not Sick'` as a flag, since it's the absence of any special behavior or the fact that including all possible categories would cause perfect multicollinearity that screws with certain models e.g regression

Comment: @toddlermenot If you're absolutely sure of what you're doing, you can also fit your `OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')` to a column with only the values you want first, then transform your column with other stuff. This way it will only OHE values that appeared in your fitted column and ignore any new values that appeared (default behavior is `handle_unknown='error'`). This is in case your testing set had values that didn't occur in your training set and you want your OHE to just go ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯